# Styles of my root component are not applied in my Angular app

Tags: css, angular

I was trying to apply a style to my app-root, however it's not being applied, please consider this stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkmfcp

In my app-component I have

```
app-root {
  background: red;
}
```

What am I missing? (Im very new to Angular...)

Where this comes from, the material angular website has in it's *root* component this style sheet

https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/material-docs-app.scss

Here they have:

```
material-docs-app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Which is basically a style for *itself* (I don't know how to explain it correclty)

I get the expected result when for example changing the index.html to this

```
<body>
  <div style="background:red;">
  <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Styles within a components CSS are only applies *within* that component. In this case, the `app-root` tag is not within the `app.component.html` file

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, please consider the updated question

Answer (score 9):

read this [article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)

try:

```
:host {
 background-color: red;
}
```

or based on comment @user184994 said Styles within a components CSS are only applies within that component. In this case, the app-root tag is not within the app.component.html, so you should add it to global css file add:

```
app-root {
  background-color: red;
}
```

to your **style.css** file of src folder.

your [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkmfcp-6bsxrf)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I updated the op, your DEMO is not really what I was looking for. I would expect the whole `app-root` tag to have in this case the red background color

Comment: @rst First thing you should know is that custom tags have display inline as default. Also in your material example you can see `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,`